# How to make div height length of page

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to get a div for content to basically run the entire height of a page between my header and my foot.  If I use:

```
  #content{ height: 100%; }
```

it only goes as high as the content I have within the div.   Sometimes I may have only 1 sentence but want the div (with a background or border) to run the length of the screen until the footer which is only about `75px` tall.

Is there a way to do this easy with CSS?  Currently what I have is:

```
  <style>
  #content {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #E0E0E0 ;
   }
  </style>
   </head>
  <body>
  <div id="content"> 
  this is a div!  with some centered crap
  </div>
```

Comment: Is it just because of backgrounds?  If so, look up "faux columns" css technique

Comment: Have you played with adding `html,body {height:100%;}​`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add: `body, html { height:100% }` and set the height of your content element to `height:100%` as well.

Comment: lol...I never thought of setting the body element to 100%, that makes sense though.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100%` to `html, body`, if it still doesnt work try positioning using `top:, bottom:, left:, right:` properties.

The problem is you're assigning a height of 100% to your div, but that is 100% of the parent element. If the parent element has no height set to it, then what is it 100% of? Adding a height attribute to `html, body` will fix that as the parent element has a height.